# Calculate distance between two points

Tags: android, android-location

I'm making an application for tracking a user as they run, cycle or walk and display it to the screen. 
I know that there is distanceBetween function built into android but is this accurate enough for a fittness application? 
I was considering using Haversine formula or other such formula for calculating distances between points the only problem I see about these formulas is that it usually is straight line or as the crow flys distances. 
Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: I suggest you specify how accurate you want it to be.

Comment: I want to be accurate to about 1 metre as will be using it to calculate the speed the user is traveling at also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Haversine formula is accurate for most distances, but it suffers from rounding errors when the points are (nearly) antipodal. The following formula is accurate for all distances.

```
> double delta = G1 - G2;  
>     double p1 = cos(L2) * sin(delta);
>     double p2 = cos(L1) * sin(L2) - sin(L1) * cos(L2) * cos(delta);  
>     double p3 = sin(L1) * sin(L2) + cos(L1) * cos(L2) * cos(delta);
>     distance = 60 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(p1*p1 + p2*p2), p3);
```

[Here's an example and the implementation.](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_distance_between_two_points_on_a_globe#Java)

resource : [Here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/12types/)

Comment: My only problem with the haversine is when they turn a corner or something but that depends on how often I get the points.

Comment: please make sure that above example give you the correct results.

Comment: Wait, what?  You accepted THIS answer?  1) It doesn't address the question 2) it is simply another crow-flight distance calculation 3) it cites a problem with haversine that occurs with points on opposite sides of the planet for your WALKING distance application 4) it's copy-and paste plagiarism.  I can't even imagine what heuristic you used to chose your answer, the fact that it was java?  Ha!

Comment: 1) For long distance use Great circle, for short please go through the link i had left @ here's an example implementation. 2) Did you check the other link? 3) The code here is for great circle n i guess you can implement it in java 4) Haversine forumals implementation is at the link i have provided 5)The questioner asked specifically " I was considering using Haversine formula or other such formula for calculating distances between points the only problem I see about these formulas is that it usually is straight line or as the crow flys distances. Does anyone have an idea about this?"

Comment: These links are still crow-flight techniques.  distanceBetween probably implements one of them.  Like I said, this answer doesn't actually answer anything.  The questions are: 1) is distanceBetween good enough and  2) any ideas on what else to do.  The questioner specifically asked about calculating points for a fitness application, it's a silly, tangential, and a red-herring to criticize haversine's ANTIPODAL deficiencies for a fitness application by copying and pasting a sentence and formula from a web page on java data types and calling it an answer.

Comment: Is earth spherical? - not exatcly! For distance 0-20 kms are you going to take earth spherical? I don't think so.

Comment: For 0 - 20 kms where you're sampling the position of a slow moving body every second you can take it as a plane!  The error in GPS and from the object turning will greatly outweigh the curvature of the earth or any changes in altitude.  Which was the point of the question by the way.

Comment: It works because of how often it is called. It is more used a work around, still will have some error in it but its very small and i did go to the link you provided. Also I ament using the map functionality because can't really look a a map when you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Tracking their route as they walk is going to involve a series of way points.  If you sample at say 1 way point every 10 seconds then you can calculate the distance between the previous point and the new point using either a crow-flys technique like haversine or just make some webservice requests to an external service like google maps and their distance matrix which can give you the snapped-to-streets distance between 2 points using suggested best path.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

You just have to make sure that your sample rate isn't too high or you can go over the 2500 API calls/24-hour-period rate limiter (which is per IP I believe). But 2500 will give you 7 hours at 1 sample per 10 seconds, or you can try a lower rate like 1 per 35 seconds and risk having the route be guessed wrong, but guarantee that your device won't go over 2500 samples.

Personally, if location polling is free, I would just go with distanceBetween and poll every 1-2 seconds.  That should be short enough that the accuracy of GPS becomes your biggest source of error.

Comment: 1 thing to add is that the TOS for using this API call requires it be used with a google map.  I would expect the mapping functionality on an android phone to be included in that, but IDK.